# Alter a table to add a column, with default 0, and then update specific rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a .sql file with:

```
ALTER TABLE `myDB`.`myTable`
  ADD COLUMN `newColumn` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0;
```

However, for some specific rows, the value in the `newColumn` should be 1.
The updated rows would be the ones where the `email` column contains specific emails. There are 5 users that need the value to be 1.

How could I do that? I am using a .sql file and importing it, so it would be good to have it all done within 1 file.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your `ALTER TABLE` statement you could add:

```
UPDATE myTable
SET newColumn = 1
WHERE email = '[your criteria]'
```